# AlertDialog onclick of ListItem in AsyncTask

Tags: android

I want to access alert dialog inside async Task onClick of ListItem. Below are the references i passed to activity  "`getbaseContext()`", "`ClassName.this`", "`this`"; but nothing worked and it would crash. Any idea ?

Async.java

public class Async extends Activity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

ListView _rssFeedListView;
List<JSONObject> jobs;
List<RssFeedStructure> rssStr;
private BlogAdapter _adapter;
TextView textview;
Context context;
AlertDialog.Builder builder
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    //context = getApplicationContext();

    _rssFeedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rssfeed_listview);
     builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading);
    RssFeedTask rssTask = new RssFeedTask();
    rssTask.execute();

    _rssFeedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
           // builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setTitle("Invitation sent unsuccesful.Please try again !");
          //  builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

            builder.setNegativeButton(
                    "Ok",null

                    );


            builder.show();


        }
    });



}


private class RssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    // private String Content;
    // private ProgressDialog Dialog;
    String response = "";
    AlertDialog.Builder alert;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            String feed = "http://url";
            XmlHandler rh = new XmlHandler();
            rssStr = rh.getLatestArticles(feed);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return response;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (rssStr != null) {

            _adapter = new BlogAdapter(Async.this, rssStr);
            _rssFeedListView.setAdapter(_adapter);
            textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }


    }

}

}
```

Error :

`07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:712)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:346)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at com.itcuties.multicategoryrssreader.BlogFeeds$1.onItemClick(BlogFeeds.java:86)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1283)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3074)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4147)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-31 16:45:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(28575):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Error received in Manish & Raji's suggestion :

`07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@41bdb010 is not valid; is your activity running?
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:708)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:346)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at com.itcuties.multicategoryrssreader.BlogFeeds$1.onItemClick(BlogFeeds.java:78)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1283)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3074)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4147)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-31 17:53:35.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8442):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: i don't see no "AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();"

Comment: bofredo : Yes i missed that, but even if i use its still not working...Edited final code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work :

Create Popupwindow Like this

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_popup_layout, null);  
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                layout, 
                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

WebView web = (WebView)layout.findViewbyId(R.id.webView1);
```

popupWindow.showAtLocation(view,Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

and create new_popup_layout layout file with webview like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="461dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

initialize context before you call the async class.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: samdroid : that's not an proper answer...don't just answer for points. Show some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this

```
getBaseContext()
```

Use

```
getAppplicationContext()
```

And also initialize context before execute Async Task like

```
this.context = getAppplicationContext();
```

And then execute

```
RssFeedTask rssTask = new RssFeedTask();
    rssTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following piece of code inside `AsyncTask` `onPostExecute()` and its working fine,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            FacebookFriends.this);
                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                    builder.setTitle("Invitation sent unsuccesful.Please try again !");
                    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

                    builder.setNegativeButton(
                            "Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(
                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Async extends Activity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

ListView _rssFeedListView;
List<JSONObject> jobs;
List<RssFeedStructure> rssStr;
private BlogAdapter _adapter;
TextView textview;
Context context;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
    _rssFeedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rssfeed_listview);

    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading);
    RssFeedTask rssTask = new RssFeedTask();
    rssTask.execute();

    this.context = getBaseContext();
```

_rssFeedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());

                    alert.setTitle("Title here");

                    WebView wv = new WebView(getBaseContext());

                    wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

                    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                                WebView view, String url) {
                            view.loadUrl(url);

                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                    alert.setView(wv);
                    alert.setNegativeButton("Close",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                }
                            });
                    alert.show();



                }
            });
}


private class RssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    // private String Content;
    // private ProgressDialog Dialog;
    String response = "";
    AlertDialog.Builder alert;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            // String feed =
            // "https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=330938752535";
            String feed = "http://srisriravishankar.org/feed/";
            XmlHandler rh = new XmlHandler();
            rssStr = rh.getLatestArticles(feed);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return response;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (rssStr != null) {

            _adapter = new BlogAdapter(Async.this, rssStr);
            _rssFeedListView.setAdapter(_adapter);
            textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



        }


    }

}

}
```

put your onItemClickListner in onCreate() Method..

Comment: Addicted Manish : I did what u suggested, and it crashed. Posting error in question

Comment: replace getBaseContext() with "this" or getAppplicationContext() at each place where you use this.

Comment: Tried that too :) But still didn't work...Edited my question again as per your suggestion. Please have a look

Comment: try this
make a global variable  AlertDialog.Builder alert;

now in onCreate() initalize it-> alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

now in setOnItemClickListner(){

alert.setMessage("Your message");
alert.setNeutralButton("Ok",null);
alert.show();
}

Comment: No Manish, It didn't work..I am editing question and showing error log. It is same which i received earlier

Comment: remove this line & see may be it works
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

Comment: Addicted Manish : Dude, please try first and then give some suggestion. Random suggestion really confuses to whom you are suggesting. However thanks for your comments

Comment: i have update your code ...your code is work for me here...please check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803915/window-manager-bad-token-exception
see this link

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your AsyncTask not from `onCreate` method of your activity, but from `onResume`. Or even after `onResume`, using for example handler. Something like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
           /*your asyncTask execution code here*/
        }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume;
    handler.post(r);
}
```

With this you will be sure that activity is really active and finished its initialization process.

Comment: Tried this, but received error. Please see my edited question for error

Comment: Try to change context here:
`builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());` , set activity itself as context.

Answer (score 0):

Create constructor of your async task and pass the context in your async task.

see following for example

```
private class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor>
    {
        Context mContext;

        asyncTask(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context


        } 
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {

        } 
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor)
        {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Invitation sent unsuccesful.Please try again !");
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

        builder.setNegativeButton(
                "Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        } 

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {

        }
    }
```

After this you can call this asynctask as

```
new asyncTask(Your_Context).execute();
```

Comment: David, its Alert Dialog and not Progress dialog. It won't work. There is only one method to instantiate alert dialog in documentation and that is : AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

Comment: I am calling async task like this : RssFeedTask rssTask = new RssFeedTask(???);
rssTask.execute();  What constructor value shall i pass inside questionmark ? I doubt it will work because it still crashes saying unable to add window error

Comment: Moreover look at your answer...You are defining alertDialog twice...Please don't make such mistakes while answering someone

Comment: yeah it was my mistake. sorry for that. and ya u should pass context in RssFeedTask rssTask = new RssFeedTask(YourClass_Name.this); rssTask.execute();